# Replace a family of coefficients by a function in a sum

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

I would like to do something very simple, i.e. replace the coefficients in a sum by a function:

```
c[1] + c[2] + c[3] /. {c[s] -> (s + 1)/(2 (2 s + 1))}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Any suggestion for something handy that would do the job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to use [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) like this:

```
c[1] + c[2] + c[3] /. {c[s_] :> (s + 1)/(2 (2 s + 1))}
(* 193/210 *)
```

This replaces every coefficient with a formula and evaluates for the integer values.